# How to bring two line in desktop view to one line in mobile view using bootstrap 2.3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

what is the best way of doing this using bootstrap 2.3?

P.S I am new to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mth4aLx3/3/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/3a4fe156e7e23a3f6c023ab0abb305e2?s=160&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fimages%2Fget-gravatar.png%3Fs%3D160&amp;r=PG" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Sub Heading</p>
    </div>
</div>
```